# Combine Matplotlib with PyQt4

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

i have a simple GUI program, when i click the `button` it will do subplot matplotlib process from `txt` file and save the image as `png` file, but i got this error even the process is success.

[image]

i try using `canvas`,`figure` but still got error, honestly i not really understand how to combine matplotlib and pyqt.

***this is my code***

```
import sys
from os import remove
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import jtextfsm as textfsm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io

class Stream(QObject):
    newText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.newText.emit(str(text))

    def flush(self):
        pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, device_type=None, ip=None, username=None, password=None, secret=None, command=None, command2=None, command3=None, command4=None):
        self.device_type = device_type
        self.ip = ip
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.secret = secret
        self.command = command
        self.command2 = command2
        self.command3 = command3
        self.command4 = command4

class sshConnection(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.window = Widget()

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.runSSH()

    def delete_file(self,name):
        remove(name + "-show-memory-statistic.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-process-cpu.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-version.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-env.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-flash.csv")
    # ------------- SSH Connection
    def runSSH(self):
        # do process
        nameFile = ['Switch-1']
        for list in nameFile:
            self.TextFSM(list)
            self.Graph(list)

    # ------------- Convert text file to CSV File
    def TextFSM(self, nameFile):
        try:
            input_file = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show version
            raw_text_data = input_file.read()
            input_file.close()

            input_file2 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show env
            raw_text_data2 = input_file2.read()
            input_file2.close()

            input_file3 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show flash
            raw_text_data3 = input_file3.read()
            input_file3.close()

            input_file4 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show memory statistic
            raw_text_data4 = input_file4.read()
            input_file4.close()

            input_file5 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show process cpu
            raw_text_data5 = input_file5.read()
            input_file5.close()

            template = open("show-version.textfsm")  # show version
            re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
            fsm_results = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data)

            template2 = open("show-env.textfsm")  # show env
            re_table2 = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
            fsm_results2 = re_table2.ParseText(raw_text_data2)

            template3 = open("show-flash.textfsm")  # show flash
            re_table3 = textfsm.TextFSM(template3)
            fsm_results3 = re_table3.ParseText(raw_text_data3)

            template4 = open("show-memory-statistic.textfsm")  # show memory statistic
            re_table4 = textfsm.TextFSM(template4)
            fsm_results4 = re_table4.ParseText(raw_text_data4)

            template5 = open("show-process-cpu.textfsm")  # show process cpu
            re_table5 = textfsm.TextFSM(template5)
            fsm_results5 = re_table5.ParseText(raw_text_data5)

            outfile_name = open(nameFile + "-show-version.csv", "w+")  # show version
            outfile = outfile_name

            outfile_name2 = open(nameFile + "-show-env.csv", "w+")  # show env
            outfile2 = outfile_name2

            outfile_name3 = open(nameFile + "-show-flash.csv", "w+")  # show flash
            outfile3 = outfile_name3

            outfile_name4 = open(nameFile + "-show-memory-statistic.csv", "w+")  # show memory statistic
            outfile4 = outfile_name4

            outfile_name5 = open(nameFile + "-show-process-cpu.csv", "w+")  # show process cpu
            outfile5 = outfile_name5

            print(re_table.header)  # show version
            for s in re_table.header:
                outfile.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results:  # show version
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table2.header)  # show env
            for s in re_table2.header:
                outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile2.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results2:  # show env
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile2.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table3.header)  # show flash
            for s in re_table3.header:
                outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile3.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results3:  # show flash
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile3.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table4.header)  # show memory statistics
            for s in re_table4.header:
                outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile4.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results4:  # show memory statistics
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile4.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table5.header)  # show process cpu
            for s in re_table5.header:
                outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile5.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results5:  # show process cpu
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile5.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

    # ------------- Convert Data to Graphic
    def Graph(self, fileName2):

        plt.figure(figsize=(8.8, 5.5), dpi=150) 
        plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'
        plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6})
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.4, right=.8, bottom=.2)

        # 1 - show flash
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-flash.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0, 1))\
                .astype(str, io.StringIO())

            slices = data[1]
            labels = data[0]
            colors = ['lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
            explode = [0.08, 0.01]
            pie = plt.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, shadow=True,
                          autopct='%1.1f%%')

            plt.title('Flash Memory\n(Bytes)')
            plt.legend(pie[0], [" ".join(a) for a in zip(labels, slices)], loc='upper right')
            plt.axis('equal')
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

        # 2 - show memory statistic
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-memory-statistic.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                              usecols=(3, 4)).astype(str, io.StringIO())
            slices = data[1]
            labels = data[0]
            colors = ['lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
            explode = [0.08, 0.01]
            pie = plt.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, shadow=True,
                          autopct='%1.1f%%')

            plt.title('Memory Statistic\n(Bytes)')
            plt.legend(pie[0], [" ".join(a) for a in zip(labels, slices)], loc='upper right')
            plt.axis('equal')
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")


        # 3 - show cpu utilization

        plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)

        def autolabel(rects):
            for rect in rects:
                height = rect.get_height()
                plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height - 2, '%1.1f%%' % int(height), ha='center',
                         va='bottom')
        N = 3
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-process-cpu.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                              usecols=(0, 1, 2)).astype(str)

            my_xticks = data[0]
            utilization = data[1]
            utilization_int = [int(x) for x in utilization]

            ind = np.arange(N)
            width = 0.5

            rects1 = plt.bar(ind, utilization_int, width, color='lightblue', )

            plt.title("CPU Utilization\n ('%') ")
            plt.xticks(ind, my_xticks)
            plt.xlabel("CPU Utilization")
            plt.ylabel("Percent(%)")

            autolabel(rects1)
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

        # 4 - CPU Environtment
        plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)

        def autolabel(rects):
            for rect in rects:
                height = rect.get_height()
                plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height - 5, '%d C' % int(height), ha='center',
                         va='bottom')

        N = 3
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=2).astype(str)
            value = data[1]
            if value == '':
                try:
                    fan = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=0).astype(str)
                    system_temp = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=1).astype(
                        str)
                    power = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=6).astype(str)
                    rps = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=7).astype(str)

                    uptime = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=3).astype(
                        str)
                    pid = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=5).astype(str)
                    sn = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=6).astype(str)

                    uptime_title = uptime[0]
                    uptime_value = uptime[1]

                    pid_title = pid[0]
                    pid_value = pid[1]

                    sn_title = sn[0]
                    sn_value = sn[1]

                    fan_title = fan[0]
                    fan_status = fan[1]

                    system_temp_title = system_temp[0]
                    system_temp_value = system_temp[1]

                    power_tile = power[0]
                    power_value = power[1]

                    rps_tile = rps[0]
                    rps_value = rps[1]

                    text = fan_title + ' : ' + fan_status + '\n' + system_temp_title + ' : ' + system_temp_value + '\n' \
                           + power_tile + ' : ' + power_value + '\n' + rps_tile + ' : ' + rps_value + ' PRESENT' + '\n\n' \
                           + uptime_title + ' : ' + uptime_value + '\n' + pid_title + ' : ' + pid_value + '\n' + sn_title\
                           + ' : ' + sn_value

                    plt.title("Cpu Environment\n ('Celcius') ")
                    plt.xlabel('CPU Environment')
                    plt.ylabel('Celcius')

                    plt.text(.15, 1 / 3, text, style='oblique', bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 5})

                    # plt.show('')
                    plt.savefig(fileName2 + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

                except (IOError):
                    print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
                    plt.savefig(fileName2 + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

            else:

                try:
                    data = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                      usecols=(2, 4, 5)).astype(str)
                    fan = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=0).astype(str)
                    system_temp = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=1).astype(
                        str)
                    system_temp_state = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                                   usecols=3).astype(str)

                    uptime = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=3).astype(
                        str)
                    pid = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=5).astype(str)
                    sn = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-version.csv', dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=6).astype(str)

                    y_height = np.loadtxt(fileName2 + '-show-env.csv', dtype=bytes, skiprows=1, delimiter=';',
                                          usecols=5).astype(int)

                    uptime_title = uptime[0]
                    uptime_value = uptime[1]

                    pid_title = pid[0]
                    pid_value = pid[1]

                    sn_title = sn[0]
                    sn_value = sn[1]

                    fan_title = fan[0]
                    fan_status = fan[1]

                    system_temp_title = system_temp[0]
                    system_temp_value = system_temp[1]

                    system_temp_state_title = system_temp_state[0]
                    system_temp_state_status = system_temp_state[1]

                    my_xticks = data[0]
                    utilization = data[1]
                    utilization_int = [int(x) for x in utilization]

                    ind = np.arange(N)
                    width = 0.5

                    text = fan_title + ': ' + fan_status + '\n' + system_temp_title + ': ' + system_temp_value + \
                           '\n' + system_temp_state_title + ': ' + system_temp_state_status

                    text2 = pid_title + ' : ' + pid_value + '\n' + sn_title + ' : ' + sn_value +\
                            '\n\n' + uptime_title + ' : ' + uptime_value

                    rects1 = plt.bar(ind, utilization_int, width, color='r')

                    plt.title("CPU Environment\n ('Celcius') ")
                    plt.xticks(ind, my_xticks)
                    plt.xlabel('CPU Environment')
                    plt.ylabel('Celcius')
                    plt.text(2.4, y_height / 2, text)
                    plt.text(-1.59, -y_height / 1.77, text2, style='oblique',
                             bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 5})
                    autolabel(rects1)

                    # plt.show()
                    plt.savefig(fileName2 + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File
                    self.delete_file(fileName2)

                except (IOError, ValueError):
                    print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
                    plt.savefig(fileName2 + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

        except (IOError):
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
            plt.savefig(fileName2 + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
            #Delete CSV File



class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Network Automation")
        self.setFixedSize(350, 500)

        # button generate and add
        self.btgenerate = QPushButton(self)
        self.btgenerate.setText('Generate')
        self.btgenerate.setFixedWidth(70)

        # Processs textedit

        self.process = QTextEdit(self)
        self.process.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(400)
        self.process.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        self.process.setReadOnly(True)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btgenerate, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.process,1,0)

        self.btgenerate.clicked.connect(self.runThread)

    def onUpdateText(self, text):
        cursor = self.process.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.process.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.process.ensureCursorVisible()


    def runThread(self):
        self.process.setText('')
        self.run_thread = sshConnection()
        self.run_thread.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
app.processEvents()
window = Widget()
sys.stdout = Stream(newText=window.onUpdateText)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**txt file**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_jl0iXmYwS_NGMxZWZEdllyVWc/view?usp=sharing

**textfsm file**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_jl0iXmYwS_ZWRFTXJjRlcxTWM?usp=sharing
(generate csv file for matplotlib required)

i hope anyone help me to fix this problem,

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not plot in a different thread to the main thread, send a signal indicating that the processing has finished, in addition to use matplotlib you must indicate the backend qt4, you could insert the plot as part of the widget as shown below:

To clear the previous window you must use the `cla()` function, in your case:

```
[ax.cla() for ax in self.axes]
```

If you want the plot to be displayed you should use the following code:

```
import io
from os import remove

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import textfsm
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QTextCursor, QSizePolicy

matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6})

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Stream(QObject):
    newText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.newText.emit(str(text))

    def flush(self):
        pass


class sshConnection(QThread):
    finishedFSM = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.runSSH()

    def runSSH(self):
        # do process
        filenames = ['Switch-1']
        for filename in filenames:
            # self.delete_file(filename)
            self.TextFSM(filename)
            self.finishedFSM.emit(filename)

    def TextFSM(self, nameFile):
        try:
            input_file = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show version
            raw_text_data = input_file.read()
            input_file.close()

            input_file2 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show env
            raw_text_data2 = input_file2.read()
            input_file2.close()

            input_file3 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show flash
            raw_text_data3 = input_file3.read()
            input_file3.close()

            input_file4 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show memory statistic
            raw_text_data4 = input_file4.read()
            input_file4.close()

            input_file5 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show process cpu
            raw_text_data5 = input_file5.read()
            input_file5.close()

            template = open("show-version.textfsm")  # show version
            re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
            fsm_results = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data)

            template2 = open("show-env.textfsm")  # show env
            re_table2 = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
            fsm_results2 = re_table2.ParseText(raw_text_data2)

            template3 = open("show-flash.textfsm")  # show flash
            re_table3 = textfsm.TextFSM(template3)
            fsm_results3 = re_table3.ParseText(raw_text_data3)

            template4 = open("show-memory-statistic.textfsm")  # show memory statistic
            re_table4 = textfsm.TextFSM(template4)
            fsm_results4 = re_table4.ParseText(raw_text_data4)

            template5 = open("show-process-cpu.textfsm")  # show process cpu
            re_table5 = textfsm.TextFSM(template5)
            fsm_results5 = re_table5.ParseText(raw_text_data5)

            outfile_name = open(nameFile + "-show-version.csv", "w+")  # show version
            outfile = outfile_name

            outfile_name2 = open(nameFile + "-show-env.csv", "w+")  # show env
            outfile2 = outfile_name2

            outfile_name3 = open(nameFile + "-show-flash.csv", "w+")  # show flash
            outfile3 = outfile_name3

            outfile_name4 = open(nameFile + "-show-memory-statistic.csv", "w+")  # show memory statistic
            outfile4 = outfile_name4

            outfile_name5 = open(nameFile + "-show-process-cpu.csv", "w+")  # show process cpu
            outfile5 = outfile_name5

            print(re_table.header)  # show version
            for s in re_table.header:
                outfile.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results:  # show version
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table2.header)  # show env
            for s in re_table2.header:
                outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile2.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results2:  # show env
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile2.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table3.header)  # show flash
            for s in re_table3.header:
                outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile3.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results3:  # show flash
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile3.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table4.header)  # show memory statistics
            for s in re_table4.header:
                outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile4.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results4:  # show memory statistics
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile4.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table5.header)  # show process cpu
            for s in re_table5.header:
                outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile5.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results5:  # show process cpu
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile5.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, figsize=(8.8, 5.5), dpi=150):
        fig = Figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)

        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.4, right=.8, bottom=.2)

        self.axes = [fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i) for i in range(1, 5)]

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def graph(self, filename):
        [ax.cla() for ax in self.axes]
        axes1, axes2, axes3, axes4 = self.axes
        colors = ['lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
        explode = [0.08, 0.01]

        # show-env
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt('{}-show-flash.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0, 1)) \
                .astype(str, io.StringIO())

            slices = data[1]
            labels = data[0]

            pie = axes1.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, shadow=True,
                            autopct='%1.1f%%')

            axes1.title.set_text('Flash Memory\n(Bytes)')
            axes1.legend(pie[0], [" ".join(a) for a in zip(labels, slices)], loc='upper right')
            axes1.axis('equal')

        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

        # show-memory-statistic

        try:

            data = np.loadtxt('{}-show-memory-statistic.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                              usecols=(3, 4)).astype(str, io.StringIO())
            slices = data[1]
            labels = data[0]
            pie = axes2.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, shadow=True,
                            autopct='%1.1f%%')

            axes2.title.set_text('Memory Statistic\n(Bytes)')
            axes2.legend(pie[0], [" ".join(a) for a in zip(labels, slices)], loc='upper right')
            axes2.axis('equal')
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

        # show-process-cpu
        N = 3

        try:
            data = np.loadtxt('{}-show-process-cpu.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                              usecols=(0, 1, 2)).astype(str)

            my_xticks = data[0]
            utilization = data[1]
            utilization_int = [int(x) for x in utilization]

            ind = np.arange(N)
            width = 0.5

            rects = axes3.bar(ind, utilization_int, width, color='lightblue', )

            axes3.set_title("CPU Utilization\n ('%') ")

            axes3.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
            axes3.set_xticklabels(my_xticks)
            axes3.set_xlabel("CPU Utilization")
            axes3.set_ylabel("Percent(%)")

            for rect in rects:
                height = rect.get_height()
                axes3.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height - 2,
                           '%1.1f%%' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")

        # show-env

        N = 3
        try:
            data = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=2).astype(str)
            value = data[1]
            if value == '':
                try:
                    fan = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=0).astype(
                        str)
                    system_temp = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                             usecols=1).astype(
                        str)
                    power = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                       usecols=6).astype(str)
                    rps = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=7).astype(
                        str)

                    uptime = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                        usecols=3).astype(
                        str)
                    pid = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                     usecols=5).astype(str)
                    sn = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                    usecols=6).astype(str)

                    uptime_title = uptime[0]
                    uptime_value = uptime[1]

                    pid_title = pid[0]
                    pid_value = pid[1]

                    sn_title = sn[0]
                    sn_value = sn[1]

                    fan_title = fan[0]
                    fan_status = fan[1]

                    system_temp_title = system_temp[0]
                    system_temp_value = system_temp[1]

                    power_tile = power[0]
                    power_value = power[1]

                    rps_tile = rps[0]
                    rps_value = rps[1]

                    text = fan_title + ' : ' + fan_status + '\n' + system_temp_title + ' : ' + system_temp_value + '\n' \
                           + power_tile + ' : ' + power_value + '\n' + rps_tile + ' : ' + rps_value + ' PRESENT' + '\n\n' \
                           + uptime_title + ' : ' + uptime_value + '\n' + pid_title + ' : ' + pid_value + '\n' + sn_title \
                           + ' : ' + sn_value

                    axes4.set_title("Cpu Environment\n ('Celcius') ")
                    axes4.set_xlabel('CPU Environment')
                    axes4.set_ylabel('Celcius')

                    axes4.text(.15, 1 / 3, text, style='oblique', bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 5})

                    # plt.show('')
                    axes4.figure.savefig('{}.png'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

                except (IOError):
                    print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
                    axes4.figure.savefig('{}.png'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

            else:

                try:
                    data = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                      usecols=(2, 4, 5)).astype(str)

                    fan = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=0).astype(
                        str)
                    system_temp = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                             usecols=1).astype(
                        str)

                    system_temp_state = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                                   usecols=3).astype(str)

                    uptime = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                        usecols=3).astype(
                        str)
                    pid = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                     usecols=5).astype(str)
                    sn = np.loadtxt('{}-show-version.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, delimiter=';',
                                    usecols=6).astype(str)
                    y_height = np.loadtxt('{}-show-env.csv'.format(filename), dtype=bytes, skiprows=1, delimiter=';',
                                          usecols=5).astype(int)

                    uptime_title = uptime[0]
                    uptime_value = uptime[1]

                    pid_title = pid[0]
                    pid_value = pid[1]

                    sn_title = sn[0]
                    sn_value = sn[1]

                    fan_title = fan[0]
                    fan_status = fan[1]

                    system_temp_title = system_temp[0]
                    system_temp_value = system_temp[1]

                    system_temp_state_title = system_temp_state[0]
                    system_temp_state_status = system_temp_state[1]

                    my_xticks = data[0]
                    utilization = data[1]
                    utilization_int = [int(x) for x in utilization]

                    ind = np.arange(N)
                    width = 0.5

                    text = fan_title + ': ' + fan_status + '\n' + system_temp_title + ': ' + system_temp_value + \
                           '\n' + system_temp_state_title + ': ' + system_temp_state_status

                    text2 = pid_title + ' : ' + pid_value + '\n' + sn_title + ' : ' + sn_value + \
                            '\n\n' + uptime_title + ' : ' + uptime_value

                    rects1 = axes4.bar(ind, utilization_int, width, color='r')

                    axes4.set_title("CPU Environment\n ('Celcius') ")

                    axes4.set_xticks(ind)
                    axes4.set_xticklabels(my_xticks)

                    axes4.set_xlabel('CPU Environment')

                    axes4.set_ylabel('Celcius')
                    axes4.text(2.4, y_height / 2, text)
                    axes4.text(-1.59, -y_height / 1.77, text2, style='oblique',
                               bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 5})

                    for rect in rects1:
                        height = rect.get_height()
                        axes4.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height - 5, '%d C' % int(height), ha='center',
                                   va='bottom')

                    axes4.figure.savefig('{}.png'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File
                    self.delete_file(filename)

                except (IOError, ValueError):
                    print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
                    axes4.figure.savefig('{}.png'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight')
                    # Delete CSV File

        except (IOError):
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
            axes4.figure.savefig('{}.png'.format(filename), bbox_inches='tight')
            # Delete CSV File

        self.draw()

    def delete_file(self, name):
        remove(name + "-show-memory-statistic.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-process-cpu.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-version.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-env.csv")
        remove(name + "-show-flash.csv")


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Network Automation")
        self.setFixedSize(350, 500)

        # button generate and add
        self.btgenerate = QPushButton(self)
        self.btgenerate.setText('Generate')
        self.btgenerate.setFixedWidth(70)

        # Processs textedit

        self.process = QTextEdit(self)
        self.process.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.process.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(400)
        self.process.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        self.process.setReadOnly(True)

        self.cv = MplCanvas()

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btgenerate, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.process, 1, 0)

        self.btgenerate.clicked.connect(self.runThread)

    def onUpdateText(self, text):
        cursor = self.process.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.process.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.process.ensureCursorVisible()

    def runThread(self):
        self.process.setText('')
        self.run_thread = sshConnection()
        self.run_thread.finishedFSM.connect(self.cv.graph)
        self.run_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    window = Widget()
    sys.stdout = Stream(newText=window.onUpdateText)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Switch-1.png**

[image]

Comment: how if i dont want to show the graph in GUI, i just need the `png` file? i try delete the `layer` that's contained show the graph and `self.draw()` but why the empty graph still appear?

Comment: i'm try to doing looping with 2 file, the first file output is normal, but why the second file output is mixed with first output so there's have 2 graph mixed into 1 file.

Comment: thanks you very much for your help, your code work well.

Comment: sorry i want ask something, why my matplotlib automatically change the size when doing loop, if there's just 1 file the size is normal but if doing loop more 2 files the size is change but not all data just a specific data even there's have `.cla()` it's still didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better please

Comment: i mean the result. when i doing loop there's have some result with different size, if i'm not doing loop or just 1 file the size is not change. this the example
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_jl0iXmYwS_d0hvVE1rWFlPNVE?usp=sharing

Comment: I notice that you have added more texts to the plot.

Comment: You could share your current code and all the data needed to run it and try to solve it.

Comment: this is my cuurent code.. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_jl0iXmYwS_YTlma1hMRUxSV00?usp=sharing

Comment: i cant add a new post because i got question ban, that why i share my code using google drive.

Comment: here's my code.. hope you can help me.. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139760/figure-sizelength-width-automatically-change-when-doing-looping